# How to put all VM-specific logs and snapshots into individual directories?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation

VirtualBox uses the directories `Logs` and `Snapshots` to store corresponding content and I like that approach pretty much. Instead, VMware stores multiple logs with their rotated files in the root directory of the VM directory by default, which decreases readability in my opinion. I've already found the setting "[log.](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/8182749)" for the [VMX file](http://www.sanbarrow.com/vmx/vmx-logging.html), but that doesn't seem to cover all log files created by VMware these days. Instead, I have the following in my directory:

- mksSandbox.log
- vmware.log
- vprintproxy.log

As the mentioned setting requires a concrete file name, it seems one can only move "vmware.log". Simply configuring a directory doesn't seem to work as well.

**So, is there a way to make VMware use a customly configured directory for logs and snapshots?**

Thanks!

Comment: Not an answer, but there's the setting `workingDir` influencing where files for snapshots get created: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1002929 Though, doesn't influence snapshots ONLY, so not the solution I'm searching for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a current version of VMware Workstation handy, but you probably should be able to change the location of the MKS log file.  The config setting *probably* is named something like `mksSandbox.log.fileName`.  You can run `strings` on the VMX and/or MKS binaries to look for it.

As for snapshots: While it's possible to move existing snapshot files (with a *lot* of manual, potentially error-prone effort), I wouldn't do it.  It's intentional that the snapshots' `.vmdk` files live alongside the originals: they're tied together.  Deleting any of them risks breaking the VM.

What you instead could consider is to move all of the virtual disk files to a separate directory, but that would be much easier to do before you create any snapshots.

Comment: Images are already placed in a individual sub-directory, because I use splitted VMDKs a lot. Having snapshots in the same dir makes things less readable again. The lock files for VMDKs are placed in the root of the VM-dir as well. Looks like VMware didn't put too much effort in the dir structure. :-/

Comment: `mksSandbox.log.fileName` doesn't work, neither any other combination I tried: `mksSandbox.logFileName`, `mks.log.fileName` `strings` doesn't reveal too much around those keywords as well. It seems that file simply can't be moved currently, maybe it's hard-coded.

Comment: Perhaps `mks.log.fileName`?  I just realized that the configuration option probably is built dynamically, which means that it likely won't directly show up in `strings` output after all.